# Creating Datasets in R with a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Thanks for any help! sorry if this is an easy question but, 
I have a .csv file with 4 columns. 
Date, Store_id, item_id, units

there are many stores, and I am trying to create datasets that are separated by store_id. it looks like i can get the data from one store with this code:

```
store_1 = train[train$store_id == 1,]
```

but this for loop does not work:

```
for (i in 1:45){
  store_[i] = train[train$store_id == [i],]
}
```

it looks like only the last store is saved

Comment: It is better not to pollute your global environment with many different data sets because it is very hard to handle. You can keep them in a list instead using `split`. Try `split(train, train$store_id)`, for instance.

Comment: ah that makes a lot of sense now. thanks for the advice!